# Finessible Bashing/Piercing Weapons

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, weapons, equipment

I'm curious to know if there are *any* specifically finessible Bludgeoning/Piercing weapons that don't require special materials, or templates to be added to be made a finessible weapon...

I know you could make a Morningstar out of Mithral, or have it Fey-crafted, or take specific feats to allow your unarmed strikes to be Bludgeoning or Piercing, but that's not what I'm looking for.

I don't care if it's a Simple, Martial or Exotic weapon, as long as it's a Finessible Bludgeoning/Piercing weapon.

I'm looking into *all* D&D 3.X and Pathfinder related materials I can get my hands on, including 2nd and 3rd part publishers.

Answer (score 7):

As [Knight Porter’s answer says](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/134366/4563), light weapons are always eligible for Weapon Finesse, which in Pathfinder means

- [cestus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cestus)—Roman, a heavy leather gauntlet used similarly to boxing gloves, but metal plates or spikes could be added to make it much more dangerous
- [kunai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunai)—Japanese, a heavy knife that was really more of a peasant’s tool than a weapon *per se*. However, ninja famously used them as an all-purpose tool and weapon, since they were easy to conceal and/or explain, and useful for things other than fighting besides.

In D&D 3.5e, there does not appear to be any such weapon. In fact, there are only four weapons with bludgeoning-and-piercing damage that I can find in the entire system—barbed chain, executioner’s mace, maquahuitl, morningstar, and tigerskull club. The barbed chain, morningstar, and tigerskull club are one-handed, the executioner’s mace and the maquahuitl are two-handed.

However, in *both* systems, a bite attack is bludgeoning, piercing, *and* slashing, all at once, which is fantastic for overcoming damage reduction, and as a natural weapon is eligible for Weapon Finesse. Natural weapons do have some awkward problems, but it’s still worth mentioning.

Tangentially, you noted feycraft, but please also note Pathfinder’s [*effortless lace*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/effortless-lace/). This is more expensive (though still quite cheap), but arguably easier to come by and it can be added to weapons after they are made, unlike feycraft weapons which must be made that way.

Comment: @HeyICanChan re: your comment on the question, I missed the barbed chain and garafa—what’s the source on those?—but I believe you missed the darktalon lizardolk’s maquahuitl from *Monster Manual IV*. Still doesn’t help, though.

Comment: The barbed chain is from *Savage Species* and the garafa is from [here.](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/article.asp?X=dl/lx20001205b3). I'd ignored the maquahuitl because of its description, thinking it was merely a greatclub variant, but you're right that it's unique in its own right. Another for the list. Thanks!

Comment: @HeyICanChan Ah, the garafa is bludgeoning *or* piercing-and-slashing; I don’t think that qualifies. Thanks for the sources though!

Comment: Time to update the ol' notes!

Answer (score 5):

Any light weapon counts as finessible. So for B&P in pathfinder, I'm seeing the Cestus and Kunai as options. Both are simple light.